# Creating a logical folder structure when creating a 7-Zip archive via the command-line

Tags: c#, powershell, zip, 7zip

I have been archiving files using the "DotNetZip" library using code like this:

```
var files = new []
{
    new { file = new FileInfo(@"C:\_test\Data\Testing\data.txt"), source = "Data" },
    new { file = new FileInfo(@"C:\_test\Logs\Testing\data.txt"), source = "Logs" },
};  

using (Ionic.Zip.ZipFile zipFile = new Ionic.Zip.ZipFile())
{
    zipFile.CompressionLevel = Ionic.Zlib.CompressionLevel.BestCompression;
    foreach (var f in files)
    {
        zipFile.AddFile(f.file.FullName, f.source);
    }
    zipFile.Save(@"C:\_test\output.zip");
}
```

The key thing to note here is that the file names are the same, they are directly contained within a folder with the same name, and when I create the Zip file I am creating logic folders for the files to sit in so there is no file name clash.

The problem is that the Zip compression is terrible. In fact I have examples of where I'm putting in a bunch of small files and getting a larger Zip!

I've then tested using 7-Zip and the results are excellent. The file sizes are much smaller than with Zip.

So, I've attempted to rewrite my code using 7-Zip, but there doesn't seem to be a good 7-Zip library for .NET and the only option is to use 7-Zip via the command line.

I've attempted this in Powershell:

```
."C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -mx9 "C:\_test\20210112 Testing.7z" "C:\_test\Data\Testing\data.txt" "C:\_test\Logs\Testing\data.txt"
```

But I get this output:

```
7-Zip 19.00 (x64) : Copyright (c) 1999-2018 Igor Pavlov : 2019-02-21

Scanning the drive:
2 files, 40 bytes (1 KiB)

Creating archive: C:\_test\__test.7z

ERROR:
Duplicate filename on disk:
data.txt
data.txt
```

If I add the `-spf` command-line then it works, but my archive is now created with every single folder starting from `C`.

Is there a way in 7-Zip to allow it to create a logical folder structure when adding items from the command line?

To be clear, I'm selecting a subset of the files in the folders to be archived and I want to place them in logical folders.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you simply want to zip up everything in the folder, then you could do this it will maintain folder structure.

```
."C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -mx9 "C:\_test\20210112 Testing.7z" "C:\_test\*"
```

**EDIT:** To selectively archive certain files, use relative paths. In your case, you could set `C:\_test` as your current directory and then run

```
."C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -mx9 "C:\_test\20210112 Testing.7z" "Data\Testing\data.txt" "Logs\Testing\data.txt"
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear in the question - I'm selectively archiving files and not archiving every file. A wildcard won't work. I have a specific subset of files that I'm archiving.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question.  I'm using 7z regularly, but never did I need such a workflow.

As you know you are getting the error due to the fact that in the archive you have duplicate file in flat structure.  The `7z` archiver does not know which one to used, thus the error.

I think you were quite close, but the issue is that you are using fully classified path to access the files for packing.

### Solution

Your solution is to run the `7z` from `C:\_test\`:

`"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -mx9 -spf2 "C:\_test\20210112_Testing.7z" "Data\Testing\data.txt" "Logs\Testing\data.txt"`

Now your archive will have the different path for the same file name.  I also recommend **not** using space in the 7z file name - you will save yourself troubles in the future.  The `-spf2` switch will adjust if you have relative or absolute path based on the input.  I tend to have it there if I should need to mix it.

### Note

I like to use the [`-spf2`](https://github.com/rikyoz/p7zip/blob/master/DOC/MANUAL/cmdline/switches/spf.htm) (does not include the drive letter in the full path) switch as that makes life easier when switching among OS.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way in 7-Zip to allow it to create a logical folder
> structure when adding items from the command line?
>
> To be clear, I'm selecting a subset of the files in the folders to be
> archived and I want to place them in logical folders.

Unfortunately, no, there is no such way in 7-Zip. The author confirmed that on his [sourceforge site](https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45798/thread/5856d980/) in 2015. Since then, there has not been [any update](https://www.7-zip.org/history.txt) on this.

The built-in PowerShell cmdlet [`Compress-Archive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/compress-archive?view=powershell-7.1) also does not support such a feature.

---

You can only achieve this by an obvious workaround: Create your logical folder structure temporarily, copy your files to it, archive this temporary folder structure and delete it afterwards. If you want to preserve the timestamps of your files - which will be altered by a regular copy operation - you can use [`Robocopy.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) (already built-in in Windows) in connection with the `/COPY:DAT /DCOPY:DAT` parameters to perform the copy operation.

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing. I have files which are **not** in a logical structure but wanted zip them in a logical structure. In the end, creating a temporary folder, performing `7z a` and then deleting it seemed like the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

We use the SevenZipSharp NuGet package for this from code. It has a CompressFileDictionary feature where it adds all the files present in the dictionary, so you can cherry pick which files to add.

Example:

```
private void CreateArchive(string archivePath, Dictionary<string, string> materialsToArchive, int part)
{
    SevenZip.SevenZipCompressor.SetLibraryPath(Properties.Settings.Default.Location7zDll);
    SevenZip.SevenZipCompressor compressor = new SevenZip.SevenZipCompressor()
    {
        CompressionMode = part == 0 ? SevenZip.CompressionMode.Create : SevenZip.CompressionMode.Append,
        ArchiveFormat = SevenZip.OutArchiveFormat.Tar,
        CompressionMethod = SevenZip.CompressionMethod.Copy,
        CompressionLevel = SevenZip.CompressionLevel.None,
        IncludeEmptyDirectories = true,
        TempFolderPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(archivePath)
    };

    compressor.Compressing += new EventHandler<SevenZip.ProgressEventArgs>(CompressorCompressing);
    lastPercent = 0;
    firstTransfer = true;
    compressor.CompressFileDictionary(materialsToArchive, archivePath);
}
```

The Key of a dictionary entry is the relative path in the zip, and Value the real path to the file...